# Calling a field from database in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
return(array($clientName,$salesPer,$prospectVal,$projID));
```

The projectID is dynamically added in database for each entry, now how can i return the ID. As i have not set any variable in PHP to map the database field.

Can anyone guide me on this.

Comment: This isn't very clear. What do you mean dynamically added - the columns are dynamically added? Can you post the table schema?

Comment: Vague question, please elaborate. The answer might be mysql_insert_id(), might be something completely different.

Comment: How to call a column name from mysql... directly

Comment: sorry, still vague, possible answers: mysql_fetch_array, mysql_field_name, SHOW COLUMNS and many more

Comment: My interpretive eyes suggest that this is a question about retrieving an autoincrementing ID from the database; $projID seems to be described as such.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to get back the ProjectID after it has been inserted into the database and automatically assigned, I suggest using something like the following:

```
$projID = mysql_insert_id();
```

immediately after running the insert statement.